# How to use emxArray_cell_wrap_0 in Visual Studio and C++?

Tags: c++, opencv

The Matlab script I used for the coder is:

```
function [B,N]=run_bwboundaries(im)
if coder.target('MATLAB')
else
    coder.rowMajor;
    [B,~,N]=bwboundaries(im);
end
```

I wanted run_bwboundaries to accept an image of any size, such as a 100x100 image of 25x 52 image

I tried the following in Matlab:

```
ARGS=cell(1,1);
ARGS{1}=coder.typeof(0, [Inf,Inf], [1,1]);
codegen -config:dll run_bwboundaries -args ARGS -report
```

I then see in the generated header file run_bwboundaries.h:

```
 extern void run_bwboundaries(const emxArray_real_T *im, emxArray_cell_wrap_0 *B, double *N)
```

but when I try the following in C++ I get a `unhandled exception access violation reading location error`:

```
run_bwboundaries_initialize();
cv::Mat im=cv::imread("input.bmp");
vector<vector<double>> imvec=matTo2Dvec(im);
double **temp;
temp=new double*[im.rows];
for(int i=0;i<im.rows;i++){
    temp[i]=new double[im.cols];
    for(int j=0;j<im.rows;j++){
        temp[i][j]=imvec[i][j];
    }
}
double* mat_ptr=&temp[0][0];
emxArray_real_T *emx = emxCreateWrapper_real_T(mat_ptr, im.rows, im.cols);
double N=0;
emxArray_cell_wrap_0 *pCW = emxCreate_cell_wrap_0(0,1);
run_bwboundaries(emx, pCW, &N);
std::cout << "N is " << N << "\n";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm...

1.
`for(int i=0;i<im.rows;i++) - for(int j=0;j<im.rows;j++)`

Rows and rows? Maybe rows and cols?

2. Try to create linear array in memory:

   ```
   run_bwboundaries_initialize();
   cv::Mat im=cv::imread("input.bmp", cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
   cv::Mat dblIm;
   im.convertTo(dblIm, CV_64FC1, 255, 0);
   emxArray_real_T *emx = emxCreateWrapper_real_T(static_cast<double*>(dblIm.data), im.rows, im.cols);
   double N=0;
   emxArray_cell_wrap_0 *pCW = emxCreate_cell_wrap_0(0,1);
   run_bwboundaries(emx, pCW, &N);
   std::cout << "N is " << N << "\n";
   ```

Comment: when I try that I get an error `static_cast: cannot convert from uchar* to double`.

Comment: I got the program to compile using `reinterpret_cast<double*>` instead of `static_cast<double*>`, but when I run the code in Visual Studio, when it reaches `run_bwboundaries(emx,pCW,&N)` it just seems to freeze and does nothing

Comment: it actually finally finished running after around 10 minutes, whereas the Matlab `bwboundaries` takes just a few seconds. Also, the value for `N` was 2, whereas in Matlab it was around 230. How can I fix this?